# Cassandra hector loader app runs out of memory

Tags: java, cassandra, hector

This simple app takes a comma delim file with headers and puts into Cassandra.
It works for small file, however the memory just goes up until out of memory exception kills it.

What am I missing?

```
package com.company;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import me.prettyprint.cassandra.serializers.StringSerializer;
import me.prettyprint.hector.api.Cluster;
import me.prettyprint.hector.api.Keyspace;
import me.prettyprint.hector.api.beans.HColumn;
import me.prettyprint.hector.api.factory.HFactory;
import me.prettyprint.hector.api.mutation.Mutator;

public class QuickLoad {
    public static Keyspace keyspace = null;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File file = new File(args[0]);
        String keyspaceName = args[1];
        String columnFamilyName = args[2];
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            keyspace = GetKeyspace(keyspaceName);
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String fileLine = null;
            String[] headers = null;
            String[] fields = null;
            boolean headerLine = true;

            while ((fileLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                if (headerLine){
                    headerLine = false;
                    headers = fileLine.substring(1, fileLine.length()-1).split("\",\"");
                } else {
                    fields = fileLine.substring(1, fileLine.length()-1).split("\",\"");
                    CassandraSave(keyspace, columnFamilyName, headers, fields);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (reader != null) {
                    reader.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public static void CassandraSave(Keyspace keyspace, String columnFamily, String[] headers, String[] columns) 
    {
        try 
        {
            Mutator mutator = HFactory.createMutator(keyspace, StringSerializer.get());
            for (int i = 1; i < headers.length-1; i++)
            {
                if ((columns[i] != null) || (!columns[i].equals("null"))) {
                    if (columns[i].length() > 0) {
                        HColumn<String, String> col = HFactory.createStringColumn(headers[i], columns[i]);
                        mutator.insert(columns[1], columnFamily, col);
                    }
                }
            }
            mutator.execute();
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static Keyspace GetKeyspace(String keyspaceName)
    {
        String serverAddress = "localhost:9160";
        Cluster cluster = HFactory.getOrCreateCluster("My Cluster", serverAddress);
        Keyspace keyspace = HFactory.createKeyspace(keyspaceName, cluster);
        return keyspace;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you add this java parameter to your code  -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError then open the heap dump with visualvm http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/heapdump.html and tell us what is taking up all the memory

Comment: I used and Eclipse Addin MAT because visualvm gave me fits

Comment: One instance of "com.ecyrd.speed4j.log.PeriodicalLog" loaded by "sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader @ 0x899902f8" occupies 127,293,432 (99.62%) bytes.

Keywords
com.ecyrd.speed4j.log.PeriodicalLog
sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader @ 0x899902f8

Answer (score 1):

I could see this as a problem if one of your 'columns' in your input file was larger than your allocated heap. You may be able to fix this by putting an upper bound on the size of your mutation, s.t. your CassandraSave function only does 100 or so mutations in a single operation.

Comment: Columns are small. The columns[] array probably wont execeed 4k

Answer (score 1):

> One instance of "com.ecyrd.speed4j.log.PeriodicalLog" loaded by
>   "sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader @ 0x899902f8" occupies 127,293,432
>   (99.62%) bytes. Keywords com.ecyrd.speed4j.log.PeriodicalLog
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader @ 0x899902f8

Looks like you are using an older version of hector and running into a [bug with speed4j leaking memory](https://github.com/rantav/hector/issues/228).  If you upgrade to hector 0.8.0-2 it should be fixed.

One thing to note is that speed4j is disabled by default in 0.8.0-2, if you want to enable it see [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/hector-users/browse_thread/thread/b4cb486e70f815f5).

Answer (score 1):

Two things I see - it's single threaded and the batch size is pretty small.

Add an outside loop to collect inserts in the mutator with a batch
size of about 500 rows to start and see how that goes.
Here is an example of performant mutator insert I use for stress testing:
https://github.com/zznate/cassandra-stress/blob/master/src/main/java/com/riptano/cassandra/stress/InsertCommand.java

Also, it is a bit older, but here is a gist of an approach to a
parallelized loader that works similarly to what you describe:
https://gist.github.com/397574